# how can I write a postgresql query to find someone's cousin in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Person(ID, name, gender, fatherID, motherID, spouseID);
This is my database columns.
for example if id = 5 how can I find this person's cousins?
i have to use just person table. And cousin means someone's mother's and father's siblings' children.
I try to use nested queries but it was too many query to follow for the result.

For example that query find someone's siblings

```
SELECT name 
FROM person 
WHERE motherid = (SELECT motherid 
                  FROM person 
                  WHERE id = x) 
  AND fatherid = (SELECT fatherid 
                  FROM person 
                  WHERE id = x) 
EXCEPT 
(SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = x);
```

Comment: Please define what *you* mean by cousin.  You should also provide sample data, desired results, and show any attempt you have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe joining to the parents of the parents, then back to their children's children.

(untested notepad scribble)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 kid.name as kid, 
 cousin.name as cousin
FROM person kid
LEFT JOIN person AS parent 
  ON parent.id IN (kid.fatherid, kid.motherid)
LEFT JOIN person AS grandparent
  ON grandparent.id IN (parent.fatherid, parent.motherid)
LEFT JOIN person AS auntcle
  ON grandparent.id IN (auntcle.fatherid, auntcle.motherid) 
 AND auntcle.id != parent.id
LEFT JOIN person AS cousin
  ON auntcle.id IN (cousin.fatherid, cousin.motherid)
WHERE cousin.fatherid != kid.fatherid AND cousin.motherid != kid.motherid -- redneck check
```